# Apache Avro Specification | Required and Optional Codecs

Tags: avro

As per the specification: https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.10.2/spec.html#Object+Container+Files
there is a mention of required codecs and optional codecs.

My question is regarding the optional codecs. For anyone implementing an Avro reader from scratch using the specification, could they skip support for optional codecs(bzip2,snappy,xz,zstandard) and still claim that their Avro reader is conforming to the specification?

Thank you.

Best regards
Sanal

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is also my interpretation of the specification.

Of course, your Avro reader won't be able to read any files that an optional codec either, but whoever has produced the compressed Avro file has been fairly warned as well.